# Process finished with exit code-073741819 when update QFrames in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt6

I have tried my program with Python 3.8 in Jetbrains and VSCode on both Windows and Linux, and this problem arises all the time.

So, I generated 99 QFrames to form this figure.
[Frames group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQtRI.png)
THis is how I write:

```
    self.insole_el_arr = []
    number = 0
    for row in range(15):
        insole_row_arr = []
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.setSpacing(8)
        hbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        hbox.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        if row == 0:
            hbox.addSpacing(0)
        if row > 11:
            hbox.addSpacing(-5 - (row - 12) * 5)
        if row > 6:
            hbox.setSpacing(11)
            hbox.addSpacing(-18)
        if row == 13:
            hbox.setSpacing(9)
        if row == 14:
            hbox.setSpacing(8)

        for col in range(7):
            pos = (row, col)
            if (pos == (0, 0)) or (pos == (0, 6)) or (pos == (13, 6)) or (pos == (14, 0)) or (pos == (14, 5)) or (
                    pos == (14, 6)):
                continue
            sqr = QFrame()
            sqr.setGeometry(row, col * 10, 15, 30)
            sqr.setFixedSize(15, 30)
            sqr.setStyleSheet('QWidget {background-color: %s}' % 'grey')
            sqr.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            hbox.addWidget(sqr)
            number += 1
            insole_row_arr.append(sqr)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)
        self.insole_el_arr.append(insole_row_arr)
```

I stored all QFrames into the insole_el_arr[], so that I can easily find them. I need to update the QFrames colors by setting their stylesheets like that:

```
            for row in range(15):
            col = 0
            mat_col = 0
            for sqr in self.insole_el_arr[row]:
                value = self.matrix_buffer[row][mat_col]
                while value == 0:
                    mat_col += 1
                    value = self.matrix_buffer[row][mat_col]
                color = self.color_buffer[row][mat_col]
                sqr.setToolTip(
                    f'({row},{col}):{value}')
                sqr.setStyleSheet(
                    'QWidget {background-color: %s}' % str(color))
                col += 1
                mat_col += 1
```

When I update the QFrames, some of them will just disappear and may reappear after the next update,
[When QFrames are updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3ffj.png)

And after several updates, the process will crashed with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005). I have no idea why this happened.
Please help me, thank you!

Comment: You're probably getting an IndexError. Run the code in a terminal or prompt and see the full traceback. That is, assuming that you're not calling any of the above using threads; in that case, just don't: widgets are not thread-safe and you cannot access them from external threads. Also, setting the geometry of a widget that is being added to a layout is pointless, since the layout will set the geometry on its own.

Comment: Huge thanks to @musicamante, I did use threads to index widgets. Everything is just fine after I abandon using threads.